# Cisco Packet Tracer, Vlan issue

Tags: networking, cisco

https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1pk7.png

As you see in the image above, I'm seeking help with making both Vlan connections (Vlan10 and Vlan20) be able to communicate with the Coffe Maker Machine, What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The way I can think of is via Inter VLAN routing

> Inter VLAN routing is a process in which we make different virtual LANs to communicate with each other irrespective of where the VLANs are present (on same switch or different switch). Inter VLAN Routing can be achieved through a layer-3 device i.e. Router or layer-3 Switch. When the Inter VLAN Routing is done through Router the it is known as Router on a stick.

So you can just assign the Coffe Maker Machine to one vlan and have the router handle the communcation. [Router on a Stick tutorial](http://www.firewall.cx/cisco-technical-knowledgebase/cisco-routers/336-cisco-router-8021q-router-stick.html)